# Tensor's shape is not compatible with supplied shape, Error in Keras Tuner

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, keras-tuner

I am using Keras tuner. For the simple following code:

```py
import keras_tuner as kt
from tensorflow.keras.regularizers import l1, l2
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential

# x: 100 x 20
# y: 1 x 100

tuner = kt.Hyperband(
            self.build_auto_encoder_model,
            objective='val_loss',
            max_epochs=30,
            hyperband_iterations=20)

tuner.search(x[0:80], y[0:80], epochs=30, validation_data=(x[80:], y[80:]))
best_model = tuner.get_best_models(1)[0]

def build_auto_encoder_model(hp):
    model = Sequential()
    regulizer_rate = hp.Choice("regulizer_rate", [1e-1, 1e-2, 1e-3, 1e-4, 1e-5])

    model.add(Dense(18, input_dim=20, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=l1(regulizer_rate)))
    model.add(Dense(12, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=l1(regulizer_rate)))
    model.add(Dense(10, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=l1(regulizer_rate)))

    model.compile(optimizer=Adam(1e-2), loss='mse')
```

I have already tried for the different number of `Dense` layers, I am getting the following error:

> Tensor's shape (20, 18) is not compatible with supplied shape (20, 15)

However, when totally, created a new project, it works. What was the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is because of some previous errors in the function code, an object has been created and loaded for any future trials, due to `overwrite` variable of the turner is `False` by default. Also, in the last version of the created object, the first layer was `15` that has been changed to `18` in your example.

A simple solution to resolve the problem (instead of creating a new project) is to make the `overwrite` variable to `True` to prevent reloading previously incompatible object with new changes, like the following:

```py
# ...
tuner = kt.Hyperband(
            self.build_auto_encoder_model,
            objective='val_loss',
            max_epochs=30,
            hyperband_iterations=20,
            overwrite = True) # here
# ...
```